# CSS to achieve a similar fixed floating div thast always on top of other divs - like stackoverflow does?

Tags: html, css, position, css-float, fixed

I'd like to achieve a similar effect as the one in this image:

[image: enter link description here]

Basically, I want to have a div as a menu bar that's always on top - the div beneath it being the container div for my content. Clicking any links in my menu bar only change the content in the container div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278085/div-with-fixed-position and many more...

Comment: @ithcy: Not much going on there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the `position: fixed;` property for #top div.

```
<div id="top"></div>

#top {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `div` and assign the CSS classes:

```
.className {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
height: 75px;
}
```

Then on your `div` have: `<div class="className">Whatever</div>`