# Just like Stackoverflow, Some floating text box at the top of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not sure whether Stackoverflow is the right place for this question, but I think it has something to do with Javascript.

Here is what I want to add to my webpage: a floating text box at the top of the webpage, you can close it by clicking the "X".

Just like the YELLOW BOX in the following picture (Welcome to Q&A blah blah....):
[image]

I tried to Google but I dont know the right phrase for this.

I have read these two questions: [CSS to achieve a similar fixed floating div thast always on top of other divs - like stackoverflow does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206413/css-to-achieve-a-similar-fixed-floating-div-thast-always-on-top-of-other-divs-l) and [div with fixed position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278085/div-with-fixed-position).

But How to add the close it by clicking the "X" button at the right?

Also, I like the color of Stackoverflow's floating text box so much. What the color is it?

Can someone give me the code that Stackoverflow uses?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use firebug and get all your answers.

Comment: Install Firebug in Firefox, or use the developer tools in Chrome - both allow you to inspect any element on a page, from which you can extract the CSS settings (color, sizing, positioning, etc...)

Comment: As for the color, make a print screen: it's `#F4A83D` for background, `#735005` for text. And SO uses jQuery :)

Comment: Create a div with the following css:
`position:absolute;
width:100%;
top:0px; 
z-index:-1'`

And for the closing part, google 'javascript onclick delete element'

Comment: For colors you can use a browser plugin such as [`EyeDropper`](http://eye-dropper.kepi.cz/) for chrome.

Comment: @Jonah Katz: do NOT use absolute, use fixed... absolute will only be the top of the page, not the top of the screen (i.e. scrolling down will make it go away)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a closing button you could use javascript or jQuery if you use jQuery, you would do something like :

HTML:

```
<div id="yellowbar">
    <div id="xbtn">x</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- load jquery-->
    <!--jquery code-->
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#xbtn").click(function(){
                $("#yellowbar").hide();
            });
        });
</script>
```

simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/dcY2A/2/

Comment: Also, you could use slideUp() or any animation you want to hide the yellow bar ... your options are only limited by your imagination (and IE)

Comment: what is the difference between `$(function() {
  $("#xbtn").click(function(){
    $("#yellowbar").hide();
});
});` and `$("#xbtn").click(function(){
    $("#yellowbar").hide();
});`
Is the additional `$(function()` in @Josh answer redundant?

Comment: oh.. actually you probably should use that additional `$(function(){....` (updated)... anything between the `$(function(){...});` runs only once the DOM is finished loading... since I put the script at the bottom, in this case it both work, if your `<script>` was above the `<div>` mine wouldn't work because the script would be referring to a `<div>` that doesn't exist yet. EX: http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/dcY2A/6/ works while http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/dcY2A/5/ does not

Comment: some tutorials even use `$(document).ready(function(){`. Which one is better? here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers They use it in the <header>.

Comment: no difference at all, `$(function(){` is just shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){`.. an abbrevaition

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a div at the top of your page with an X button like so:

```
<div class="floatingBox" id="message1">
  <span class="message">Your message</span>
  <img src="x-button.png" id="closeButton"/>
</div>
```

You can make the close button hide the message box using jQuery like so:

```
$(function() {
  $('#closeButton').click(function() {
    $('#message1').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely the right place to ask this question!

- The background color of the floating box is: `F4A83D`
- The border color of the floating box is: `D6800C`
- The text color in the floating box is: `735005`

Here's a fiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/FQ3fz/

Note that I'm using jQuery. If you want a pure JavaScript solution, let me know :)

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 1):

You can check out meerkat plugin.

http://www.jarodtaylor.com/meerkat/howto/

Answer (score 0):

Here!

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/RGsxd/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // add some 'if unknown user' check.
       var infoH = $('#infobar').height();
       $('#infobar').animate({top:'0px'},1000);
       $('#infoclose').click(function(){
          $('#infobar').animate({ top:'-'+infoH },1000);
       });
    // close 'if'

});
```

The only difference is that in my demo the bar is positioned absolutely, but you can adjust the css as you like.

P.S. are the colors ok? ;)